# PHP object data

Tags: php, arrays

can someone tell me how to get the e.g Firstname or Email value from this array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => User Object
        (
            [UserId:UserData:private] => 1
            [Enabled:UserData:private] => 1
            [RbComms:UserData:private] => 0
            [UserLevel:UserData:private] => Admin
            [Password:UserData:private] => 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
            [IP:UserData:private] => 
            [BalanceReminder:UserData:private] => 0
            [ThirdpartyComms:UserData:private] => 0
            [CreationTime:UserData:private] => 2011-07-04 14:04:00
            [Browser:UserData:private] => 
            [Email:UserData:private] => admin@admin.com
            [Username:UserData:private] => admin
            [Mobile:UserData:private] => 5465651651
            [Latitude:UserData:private] => 
            [Firstname:UserData:private] => Admin
            [Lastname:UserData:private] => Henderson
            [Longitude:UserData:private] => 
            [Balance:UserData:private] => 0.00
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

They are private members, so you need to use the User class' methods to get at them.

These are usually something like `$myuser->getEmail()`, but it depends on how it is defined in the class.  Read its source code to find out.

Comment: did you meant `$myuser->getEmail();` as it is a method call not accessing a property directly.

Comment: Or make them accessible via Reflection.

Comment: @Paul, good catch.  @hakre, surely the best approach would be to access the method in the way intended by the class, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
$the_array[0]->Firstname
```

or

```
$the_array[0]->Email
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array[0]->Firstname;
```

or, more properly:

```
foreach ($array as $user)
{
    echo $user->Firstname;
}
```

Edit: Brad's answer is also correct, as these are private variables, the class should also provide "get" methods, such as

```
$array[0]->GetFirstname();
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting syntax. I'd try this:

```
 var_dump( $array[0]->Email );
```